# Procedure issues SQL Server getting an error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the issue with the `PLSQL` procedure I have, passing the values as numeric values but I am getting errors

here is my procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_rivereast_fee_insert  


   @_fee varchar(255),
   @_scheduleid varchar(100)

AS 
   BEGIN

      SET  XACT_ABORT  ON

      SET  NOCOUNT  ON 
            
            DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

      SET @_id = NULL

            WHILE @cnt <= COUNT(@_scheduleid) 
            
            BEGIN
            
                    INSERT rivereast_fee(fee, scheduleid, createdon, updatedon)
                        VALUES (@_fee, @_scheduleid, getdate(), getdate())
                    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;    
            END         

   

      SELECT @_id = scope_identity()

   END
```

I am getting an error like this

> Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
> Driver][SQLServer]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
> '1021,1019' to data type int. 
> The error occurred on line 120.
> {call usp_rivereast_fee_insert(@_id = (param 1) , @_fee = (param 2) ,
> @_scheduleid = (param 3) )}

Comment: The error is **literally** telling you the problem... `'1021,1019'` isn't an integer...

Comment: Also, what is `COUNT(@_scheduleid)` trying to achieve? It's either going to return 1 or 0, as `@_scheduleid` is a `varchar`; a scalar value. It either has a value or doesn't.

Comment: Your stored procedure code will not compile - so obviously that is not the actual stored procedure you are attempting to execute. Don't add more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense:

```
WHILE @cnt <= COUNT(@_scheduleid)
```

Your code has other issues as well, such as `@id` not being defined.

Makes no sense.  I suspect you are passing `@_scheduleid` as a comma-delimited value.

If so, the code you would want is:

```
INSERT rivereast_fee(fee, scheduleid, createdon, updatedon)
    SELECT @_fee, s.value, getdate(), getdate()
    FROM string_split(@_scheduleid, ',') s;
```

You can use an `OUTPUT` clause if you want to return the ids that are inserted.

This replaces the entire body of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_rivereast_fee_insert (
   @_fee varchar(255),
   @_scheduleid varchar(100)
) AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT rivereast_fee(fee, scheduleid, createdon, updatedon)
        SELECT @_fee, s.value, getdate(), getdate()
        FROM string_split(@_scheduleid, ',') s;
END;
```

Comment: can you modify the procedure because if the while does not work, potentially the the way you explained should work